# Playing Different Sound Files In Java

Tags: java, audio

I am trying to play multiple sound files at different times in Java.  I am doing this by stopping one file and then starting another file after a few seconds.  However, whenever I do this, Java either freezes or throws an error whenever I try and switch files.  This is the function I am using to play different files:

```
public void backgroundSound(String musicFile){
    System.out.println("1");
    if(this.clip!= null){
        if(this.clip.isRunning()){
            this.clip.close();
         }
    }
    System.out.println("2");
    try{
        File soundFile = new File(musicFile);
        AudioInputStream audioIn =
            AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
        this.clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        this.clip.open(audioIn); // line 538
        this.clip.start();
        this.clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
    }

    catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the stack trace when using `this.clip.flush()` instead of `this.clip.close()`:

```
javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.
        at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.implOpen(DirectAudioDevice.java:492)
        at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.implOpen(DirectAudioDevice.java:1278)
        at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(AbstractDataLine.java:107)
        at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.open(DirectAudioDevice.java:1059)
        at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.open(DirectAudioDevice.java:1149)
        at MyGame.backgroundSound(MyGame.java:538)
        at MyGame.actionPerformed(MyGame.java:161)
        at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:291)
        at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:221)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:666)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:81)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:627)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:625)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:636)
        ...
```

Comment: Do you have the specific error?

Comment: java completely freezes on me and stops working so for the specific error its hard to pinpoint.  However, if if I change
this.clip.close() to this.clip.flush(), 
java throws an error at the line:
this.clip.open(audioIn) when I change music files

Comment: We need the error. Can you run it in an IDE with debug and see the stack trace?

Comment: For more specific detail, I believe the error comes from this.clip.close() because when I run the music files it freezes between the print statements of 1 and 2

Comment: Here is the stack trace:

Comment: Whatever line 538 is on your MyGame class is what the error originates from. Is that the line of `.close()`?

Comment: no that is the line, 
this.clip.open(audioIn); // line 538